# how to obtain execution time profile for a nodejs sails application

Tags: sails.js, profile, execution-time

I have a nodejs back-end API application implemented using sails.
Is there some way for me to know how much time was spent in each of my app  functions, after I hit specific http routes in the app?
Thanks.

EDIT: I tried using
`node --prof /pathToSails/sails lift` but the resulting profile didn't mention any of my own functions.  Seems more like a profile of sails' own functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different direction at solving my problem, but in case someone is wondering, there is the options of using `sails debug` together with `node-inspector`.

This is briefly documented in the sails debug doc page, with more details on the node-inspector README file, on specifics about how to start and end the profiling.